# Noda Time: Period.Between() 01/01/2023 and 31/12/2023 returns 11 months instead of 12

Tags: c#, nodatime

I am trying to get the number of months between two DateTime objects.

I am using NodaTime. And my two DateTime values are:

- Start: 01/01/2023
- End: 31/12/2023

Here's my code:

```
// period in months between start and end date
LocalDateTime startDate = LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(request.Entity.StartDatetime.Value);
LocalDateTime endDate = LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(request.Entity.FinishDatetime.Value);
Period period = Period.Between(startDate, endDate, PeriodUnits.Months);
int numberOfMonths = period.Months;
```

I expect `numberOfMonths` to be `12`, but instead, I'm getting `11`.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: why would it be 12? if it where truly 12 the date would be 01/01/2024 its one day to short for 12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unsurprisingly this code gives 12 months:

```
LocalDateTime startDate = LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(new DateTime(2023, 1, 1));
LocalDateTime endDate = LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(new DateTime(2024, 1, 1));
Period period = Period.Between(startDate, endDate, PeriodUnits.Months);
int numberOfMonths = period.Months;
```

The key is that 12 months have actually elapsed.

If you're looking at `2023/12/31` then it's actually `2023/12/31 00:00` and is a day short of 12 months.

Comment: ah I got it, thank you <3

Comment: Sorry, forgot to ask. Is there a way I can find out if the period is over 12 months? e.g. 12 months and x days?

Comment: @RedPanda83 - couldn't find single line, but you could always add the months to the start date and than again get `Period.Between` for days. eg. https://dotnetfiddle.net/0EKcbF